# How to show a second view on a window controller with toolbar?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, segue

I added a toolbar with 2 items(A and B) to a window controller.

[image]

I'm trying to show a second view(B) on the same place as the first view(A) on a window controller.

I tried segue and it shows me a few options (sheet, show, custom, modal and popover). None does what I would like. The closest one was sheet.

For the first view I can see a relationship (window content to view controller) and it seems to be what I need.

The end result would be a preference window with toolbar to show different views. In some applications I see the window size changing, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

After reading more and more, I did it by:

1 - Add a Tab View Controller

2 - Add image to each Tab View Item

3 - Change the style on Tab View Controller to Toolbar